# How can I remove a keyboard layout that isn't listed in the control panel?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

Here's an interesting oddity:

- My work computer comes with a corporate disk image preloaded, and it is preconfigured with the **German "QWERTZ" keyboard layout.**
- Using the control panel, **I added my preferred QWERTY layout** so I could type without going nuts over the swapped Y and Z keys (and many of the special characters like ' * ^ # that I use a lot).
- Windows has never been good at handling multiple keyboard layouts and it kept switching back to German. So **I removed the German keyboard** altogether.
- **PROBLEM:** My computer still switches itself back to German every now and then, and there's no way to get away from that again. I see the language selector (see screenshot) and I can choose the non-German item, but as soon as I click inside another window, the indicator jumps back to German. Only a reboot helps... for a while.
- I've tried installing the German language and then removing it again, but it still remained. I also tried installing the German language with several layouts including US English, and then the list contained *three* languages: English was listed as a language even though it was only installed *as a layout.* Rebooted, then uninstalled the German and all its layouts again.
  --> Now I have Danish **+ English** instead of Danish + German... ?! Windows is still broken but in a better way because at least I got rid of the swapped Y & Z keys.

Screenshot: The indicator shows that the German keyboard is active -- ***but it's not even installed!!?!*** What is this sorcery? How can I get rid of that German layout?

[image: wtf?] [image]

Comment: The layout seems to be arising from the language bar - have you checked that tab?

Comment: @Sathya I added another screenshot -- nothing special there, as you can see.

Comment: Could you make a screenshot for each of the following registry keys? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload` ; `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\Assemblies` ; `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\AssemblyItem` ; `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language`